Looking for title about time traveler finding empty cities and dying human civilization
Man meets a time traveler in Nevada desert. The time traveler came from the far future to find wondrous machines, empty cities, and humanity in decline. Builds a curious machine.

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Are there any extra details you remember that you could [edit] in? Was this a movie or a TV series or a book? When did you read/watch this?

Twilight by John W. Campbell, Jr. (1934).
In the Nevada desert, a man picks up a hitchhiker dressed in odd silver clothing.
The hitchhiker says he is a time traveller from the future. He was returning from a visit to the ultra far future, and when trying to return to his home time overshot a bit.
The time traveler says in the ultra far future there are advanced machines, cities that are mostly empty, and a few decadent humans who are also hyper-intelligent. The machines are keeping everything running, but they have no initiative.
The time traveller makes a new machine which has curiosity. Hopefully this machine will evolve some initiative, and take over when man becomes extinct.

Campbell also wrote a sequel of sorts, "Night."

machine with curiosity achieves initiative, humankind becomes extinct.

The Time Machine - H.G. Wells
Also follows the same flow. A scientist builds a time machine into the future and finds Earth in a dilapidated state and the sun is dying while humans have regressed evolutionary-ily after conquering Science and Nature

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The Time Machine is told from the traveller's viewpoint; this story has the time traveller meet the protagonist, so it's substantially different.

Also, the Nevada desert doesn't feature in Wells' novella, which is set entirely in England (or what's left of that land mass in the distant future).
